# Proper way to access Component config from API?

Tags: development, custom-component, joomla-4.x

I am building a custom admin component for Joomla!4 that includes an API.

To access the component's config I am using, on the API Controller file:

```
$params = ComponentHelper::getComponent('com_mycomponent')->getParams();
```

It seems a bit off to me to have go via the Component Helper to get my own component's params - in spite am I working on the API part of the code.

It works fine, but is that the proper way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "more direct" way is:

```
ComponentHelper::getParams('com_example');
```

||

```
ComponentHelper::getParams('com_example')->get('yourParam');
```

But yes, is through ComponentHelper class